# Add key and values to an object in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

I would like to add key and values to my objects in resultLog, and I've tried couple of different things but haven't got it to work.
(see further down what I would like to achieve).

This is my output so far:

I have pushed my array into objects and added keys.....but now Im stuck.

```
let result = [5, 4, 1, 1];
let resultLog = [];

for (let i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i += 2) {
  resultLog.push({ pageViews: result[i], visitors: result[i + 1] });
}
console.log(resultLog);
// output [{pageViews: 5, visitors: 4},{ pageViews: 1, visitors: 1}]
```

I need to add key and value to each object, but how can I do that?
I've had a look at `.splice` or `.unshift` but can't get it to work.

This is what I would like it to look like:

```
let result = [
  { url: "/contac.html", pageViews: 5, visitors: 4 },
  { url: "/home.html", pageViews: 1, visitors: 1 }
];

console.log(result)
console.table(result);
```

This is the array that I extracted the number of unique users of each url and number of pageViews.

```
const filtered =[
"|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12345 |", 
"|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12346 |",
"|2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12345 |", 
"|2019-03-01 10:30:00UTC |/home.html    |12347 |", 
"|2019-03-01 11:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12347 |", 
"|2019-03-02 11:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12348 |"]
```

Comment: how exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Your expected result looks almost like the current one, there's just another member.

Comment: @NithinChandran
I would like to add another member to my objects, I would like to add these two keys and values url: "/contac.html", url: "/home.html" to a object each, is that more clear?

Comment: Where come that values from? Are they in an array already ordered to match the first array `result = [5, 4, 1, 1]` ?

Comment: @Cid the values comes from another ( the original )array that I destructured, 
the values Im trying to add to this new array is also in the original....maybe Im making it more complicated that I need to?

New to coding so trying to figuring it all out.

Comment: Show us that array, it's actually missing

Comment: @Cid Ive added the array to my question. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var obj= {array:[]};
for (let i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i += 2) {
  obj.array.push({ pageViews: result[i], visitors: result[i + 1] });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filtered = [
"|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12345 |",
"|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12346 |",
"|2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12345 |",
"|2019-03-01 10:30:00UTC |/home.html    |12347 |",
"|2019-03-01 11:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12347 |",
"|2019-03-02 11:00:00UTC |/contact.html |12348 |"]
```

1.statistics page views and visitors

```
 const pageDict = filtered.reduce((prev, cur) => {
    // remove first `|` and last `|`
    const record = cur.replace(/(^\|)|(\|$)/g, '');
    const [time, url, userId] = record.split('|').map((v) => v.trim());
    if (url in prev) {
        prev[url].pageViews++;
        prev[url].visitors.add(userId);
    } else {
        // if url not in prev, init 
        prev[url] = {
            pageViews: 1,
            visitors: new Set([userId]),
        }
    }
    return prev;
}, {});
```

2.format data

```
  const result = Object.entries(pageDict).map(([key, value]) => {
    const { pageViews, visitors } = value;
    return {
        url: key,
        pageViews: pageViews,
        visitors: visitors.size,
    }
})
console.log(result);
```

3. print result is:

   ```
      [
    { url: '/contact.html', pageViews: 5, visitors: 4 },
    { url: '/home.html', pageViews: 1, visitors: 1 }]
   ```